# Regex to find whole word in text but case insensitive

Tags: regex

I have the following text:

> I like a bit of rum with my crumble pie.

I want to build a regex search expression to return just the word 'rum' not 'crumble' as well. Also I need it to be case insensitive.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? For what language do you need it? have you tried something to help write your regex? -> https://www.debuggex.com/

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use word boundary `\b` in your regex,

```
(?i)\brum\b
```

**OR**

Use lookahead and lookbehind,

```
(?i)(?<= |^)rum(?= |$)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fQ6sV3/8)

Comment: In my quick test of this I think it does not work for when it is the last word in a sentance. I.e. "rum." or "rum!".

Comment: So maybe try this `(?i)(?<=\s|^|\W)rum(?=\s|$|\W)` in the case ppl using tab, I replace ' ' by \s

Comment: In place of word and I have a string  with spaces and want to compare strings ignoring spaces e.g. match  'I Love You' with 'i   love       you'